# finally is skipped if the catch is triggered

Tags: powershell

this is PS 5.1

```
try {
    Send-MailMessage -to $EmailTo -Body $Body -Subject "$TodayDate Report" -From 'r-admin@domain.com' -SmtpServer 'mail-relay' -port '25' -BodyAsHtml -ErrorAction Stop
}
Catch {
    Write-Warning "Unable to send email"
    & gam user $($EmailTo) sendemail html true to $($EmailTo) subject "$TodayDate Report"
}
finally {
       #final cleanup
    If (@($UsersResultsArray).count -gt 0) {
        remove-Item $UsersResultFileName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    IF ($ArchiveOverFlowCount -gt 0) {
        remove-Item $ArchiveOverFilename -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    If ($ZeroCount -gt 0) {
        remove-item $ZeroArrayFileName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }

    remove-Item $NumbersTableFilename -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
```

I have tried many combinations but if the `try` gets an error the `catch` works but the `finally` does not.

I have tried no `finally` and nothing happens after the `catch`.

No errors.
I am not sure what is going on or why nothing happens after the `catch`?

If the `Try` does not get an error everything works fine.

I tested with a `continue` in the `catch` and whatever I do if the `catch` fires the `finally` does not.

Comment: Does the `continue`  continue a loop? In that case you jump out of the whole exception structure.

Comment: the finally block gets executed in any case. but why do you have ```continue``` in the catch - does this run within a loop?

Comment: why do you think finally did not get executed? are those files still there or what is the indication? If this is the complete code its quite simple, those variables in the IF statements are empty, so nothing happens except: ```remove-Item $NumbersTableFilename -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue``` but this will only have a effect if the variable ```$NumbersTableFilename``` contains paths...

Comment: the files are there after the ```catch```. I see them but if the ```try``` works they get deleted.
The difference is if VPN is on or off.
The paths are good because if I single line run the files get deleted. 
@Toni

Comment: Where are the other variables coming from? When the pipeline is stopped, depending on where the variables are declared, they won't be assigned. You have to force it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

*The finally keyword is followed by a statement list that runs every time the script is run, even if the try statement ran without error or an error was caught in a catch statement.*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.2

Now lets test:

```
try {
    get-item C:\nothing.there -ErrorAction:Stop
}
catch {
    write-error $_
}
finally {
    write-host "finally"
}

#Output:
Write-Error: Cannot find path 'C:\nothing.there' because it does not exist.
finally
```

So the catch caught the error and finally got executed.

```
try {
    get-item C:\Windows -ErrorAction:Stop
}
catch {
    write-error $_
}
finally {
    write-host "finally"
}

#Output:
    Directory: C:\

Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d----          12/10/2022    22:29                Windows
finally
```

Once again finally got executed.

So back to your example, I think that the variables used in the IF statements, e.g. `$UsersResultsArray`, are empty or the variables that should contain paths like `$UsersResultFileName`.

To verify if the finally block runs, simply add `write-host "finally"` to that block and re-run the code, you will see "finally" printed on the screen.

Btw. to verify if the variable holds elements you do not need to count them, this is enough: `IF ($UsersResultsArray){}`.